# Zustand: typescript subscribe

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

How to use `subcribe` method in typescript ? I getting error `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'BearState'`

```
//store.ts
import { create } from 'zustand'

interface BearState {
  bears: number
  increase: (by: number) => void
}

export const useBearStore = create<BearState>()((set) => ({
  bears: 0,
  increase: (by) => set((state) => ({ bears: state.bears + by })),
}))
```

```
//App.tsx

function App() {
    const bearStore = useBearStore()
    const unsub = bearStore.subscribe(console.log)

    return (
        <div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: `useBearStore.subscribe(...)`